# PDF as blank page in HTML

Tags: html, css, pdf, laravel-5

My problem is, everything is fine opening PDFs using my browsers, until I uploaded a pdf with a form inside. Then, if I embed it, it returns a blank page. But the other pdfs with forms open normally. Please see my code below:

```
<object data="{{ asset($test->file_path) }}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <embed src="{{ asset($test->file_path) }}" type='application/pdf'>
    <center>
        <a href="{{ route('download.test', ['id' => $test->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Please click here to view</a>
    </center>
</object>
```

Note: I've also tried to use `<iframe>` but still returns blank page.

## Solution:

***option1:***

Renamed my file that has `#` sign. And everything should work fine.

***option2:***

Use `urlencode` if needed.

Comment: Can you publish a fiddle or an example PDF that causes the bug?

Comment: Hi @Thomas . If I create a fiddle, this also won't work because I'm using laravel. Sorry for that, but this is an example of my pdf with form, http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf.

Comment: I just tested it locally in Chrome 63 (Windows 10) and it worked. Which browsers/versions did you try and on which OS?

Comment: Can you check that file if its not corrupt.

Answer (score 6):

```
<a href="{{ route('download.test', ['id' => $test->id] ,['target'=>'_blank']) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Please click here to view</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's late, and I'm tired, so apologies if I misread the question.

I noticed that the PDF is hosted on a site that doesn't support HTTPS. It showed a blank page if it was embedded on a site using HTTPS, but worked fine when it was using HTTP.

I think you need to either move the PDF to a site that supports HTTPS or make the site hosting the PDF start using HTTPS.

Comment: Hi @SigaVPN. I'm still using localhost which uses `http` and the pdf file is also inside my project which also an `http` file.

Comment: @Jonjie try using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Objects and Iframes (Rather than Object and Embed)

Something like this should work for you:

```
<object data="http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <iframe src="http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none;">
        This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="/pdf/example.pdf">Download PDF</a>
    </iframe>
</object>
```

This worked when I tested it locally but I can't show JSFiddle since it uses HTTPS. 
Also, have a look at these examples: https://pdfobject.com/static.html

Comment: This browser does not support PDFs -> This browser does not support IFRAMES. The browser before downloading "OoPdfFormExample.pdf" doesn't know that suport the mime format. The `<iframe/>` is created in the moment. The browser by default will show garbage in `<iframe/>` or blank `<iframe/>` with popup download window if default action for PDF mime type is set.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work as I am not able to test your case. You can try this, it always works for me. Try replacing http://yoursite.com/the.pdf with the correct path.

```
<object data="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="750px" height="750px">
    <embed src="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" type="application/pdf">
        <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
    </embed>
</object>
```